# Upload files to FTP

Tags: 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure D7 so files get uploaded to a different server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30411/how-to-configure-d7-so-files-get-uploaded-to-a-different-server)

I have a field "upload PDF File" in a content type "ABC". I want the ability to upload files to FTP server.

How to achieve this.

Comment: @googletorp:"How to configure D7 so files get uploaded to a different server" question is not clear specially for newbie like me. If it's answered in a more elaborated way it would be helpful.

Comment: The idea behind SE is to avoid having duplicate questions - in this case uploading files to a different server. If the answers in the question doesn't solve your needs, you could improve the question to get better answers, (help others who come across the same issue) instead of creating multiple versions of the same answer, none with the perfect solution.